# String Split AND Replace

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I am trying to replace a string based on the split portion. This string is a date, where  the year should be formatted as a superscript.

Eg. `Jan 24, 2014` needs to be split at 2014 then replaced with `Jan 24, ^2014^` where 2014 is the superscript.

Example pseudo:

```
mydate.Split(" ", 2).Replace("^2014^")
```

But, instead of replacing the new split string, it should be the original (or copy of original). I can't just edit based on index because the formatting may not always be the same, at times the date may be expanded to `January 24th, 2014` which would then break the traditional replace by index.

Comment: What's the desired output exactly? A second string containing `Jan 24, ^2014^`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
(?<=[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{2}, )(\d{4})
```

Replaced with `^$1^` or `^\1^`

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/rZ1rH5/1) and tested it on [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5bA-Z%5d%5ba-z%5d%7b2%7d+%5cd%7b2%7d%2c+)(%5cd%7b4%7d)&i=Jan+24%2c+2014&r=%5e%241%5e)

---

If you want to match `January 24th, 2014` as well then try

```
([A-Z][a-z]{2,9} \d{2}[a-z]{0,2}, )(\d{4})
```

Replaced with `$1^$2^`

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rZ1rH5/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of lookarounds to achieve your result.

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=\d{4})|(?=\d{4})", "^")
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?<=        #  look behind to see if there is:
  \d{4}     #    digits (0-9) (4 times)
)           #  end of look-behind
|           # OR
(?=         #  look ahead to see if there is:
  \d{4}     #    digits (0-9) (4 times)
)           #  end of look-ahead
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aD1aN9/2)

Answer (score 0):

Normalize you date string by assigning it to a Date variable, then do the formatting from there.

```
    Dim dt As Date = "Jan 24, 2014"
    Dim s As String = dt.ToShortDateString.Replace("2014", "^2014^")
    MsgBox(s)
    ' or '
    s = dt.Month.ToString & "/" & dt.Day.ToString & "/^" & dt.Year.ToString & "^"
    MsgBox(s)
```

IMO RegEx is write once code and is difficult to debug/maintain.